# Download a package from a PPA as standalone file

Tags: ppa

I want to download (not install) a package from a PPA repository without adding the PPA by `apt-add-repository` and then updating APT cache. (Because updating cache can takes a long time and then I have to remove the PPA afterwards)

Is there a way to download the package by a web browser as a standalone file, `.deb` for example?

Comment: Have you tried go to this PPA site you don't mention?  Launchpad.net

Comment: @xangua Yes, I want to download *picard* package from [this PPA](https://launchpad.net/~musicbrainz-developers/+archive/ubuntu/stable)

Comment: Yes you can download it from there, so what's the issue? Please remember when you use a Third Party Repository or install an unsigned .deb package you are on your own, that means you are the responsible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Click on **View package details** on top right of the screen and search for your desired package.

[image]

Now click on your package. Under this package you can see **Package files**. Select the one you want.

[image]

Comment: Hi, I can't find those on the [Remmina](https://launchpad.net/~remmina-ppa-team/+archive/ubuntu/remmina-next/+packages) source. Any idea?